# Block statements in anonymous Scala function

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I've created this simple anonymous function

```
var b = (x : Int) => if(x % 2 == 0) x + 1 else x
```

and it works great. After that I tried to add another statement after the if and before the `x+1` statement.

```
var b = (x : Int) => if(x % 2 == 0) println(x) x + 1 else x
```

and a that point I received the following compiler error

> Cannot resolve symbol x

Please can anyone let me know why this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this happens is that although Scala does not require the use of semi-colons most of the time (unlike Java), since the compiler is more equipped to infer where statements/expressions end, if you have 2 statements/expressions on 1 line then you need to separate them for the compiler.

Your first anonymous function works since `if(x % 2 == 0) x + 1 else x` is 1 expression.

The compiler is complaining with the second one though since `if(x % 2 == 0) println(x)` is considered 1 statement. Hence, the next statement starts and there is now no context for `x`.

Other posters have given you a solution to break the right-side of the function down into separate statements so I won't duplicate - just adding an explanation of why the compilation error occurs since you said you are learning the language. Google about the use of semi-colons in Scala to find out more.

Answer (score 6):

Use this. You need the braces to indicate these are multiple lines:

```
var b = (x : Int) => if(x % 2 == 0) {
    println(x) 
    x + 1 
} else x
```

Or you can do this.. you need to put that semi colon to indicate to compiler they are separate statements:

```
var b = (x : Int) => if(x % 2 == 0) { println(x); x + 1 } else x
```